# Preimage of product of chraccteristic function compared to preimage of function

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, characteristic-functions

Let $g:X \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function and $A$ be a subset of $X$. Let $(g\chi_A)(x) = \begin{cases} 
      g(x) \mkern3mu &x\in A \\
      0 \mkern3mu &x \notin A
   \end{cases}
$. I want to write $(g\chi_A)^{-1}(B)$ in terms of $g^{-1}(B)$, where $B$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

I know that $g^{-1}(B)=\{x \in X : g(x) \in B\}$. And $(g\chi_A)^{-1}(B)=\{x \in X :(g\chi_A)(x) \in B\}$. But we can write
\begin{align*}
(g\chi_A)^{-1}(B)&=\{x \in A :(g\chi_A)(x) \in B\} \cup \{x \in A^c :(g\chi_A)(x) \in B\} \\
&=\{x \in A :g(x) \in B\} \cup \{x \in A^c :0 \in B\} 
\end{align*}

So to me this implies that $(g\chi_A)^{-1}(B) = \begin{cases} 
      (g^{-1}(B) \cap A) \cup A^c \mkern1mu &0 \in B \\
      g^{-1}(B) \cap A  \mkern3mu &0 \notin B
   \end{cases}$.

Is this logic correct?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thanks for your reply. I don't quite see how the $0 \in B$ case simplifies to $g^{-1}(B)$, could you please elaborate on that? And is there any way to write this answer without defining the cases separately?

Comment: Mental hiccup on my part: you’re quite right that it need not be $g^{-1}[B]$. No, I don’t see any way to avoid a definition by cases.

Comment: You can write that if you wish but as far as I writing that, I won't because you already written that.   Therefore we cannot write that.

Comment: @WilliamElliot I'm sorry, I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I think you might be able to use the fact that union distributes over intersection to write $(g^{-1}(B) \cap A) \cup A^c=\(A^c \cup A)\ \cap \(A^c \cup g^{-1}(B) \) =A^c \cup g^{-1}(B) $

Comment: @A.B: Yes, that works (and may even have been what I was actually thinking of when I wrote that other nonsense).

Comment: @A.B.  I'm referring to the sentence that begins "But can we write".